# For 2 orthogonal vectors, is tan(a)tan(b)=-1?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-writing, vectors, proof-explanation

[image]

This is a part of a physics subproblem I was solving where in the solution they casually mentioned:-
$\begin{align}\\
tan(A) \times tan(B) = -1
\end{align}\\$

Without proving it, and proceeded to solve the complete question. I tried using `ASS` similarity methods but it yielded a totally different result.

I am willing to post my physics question here in case someone thinks this is an [XY scenario](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) or I got something wrong! :]

Comment: Hint: $A + B = \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: That's a well known and easily proved fact. Start from the definition of $\tan$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $\tan(A) \tan(B) = 1$, for all $A,B$ satisfying $A+B = 90$ ?

Comment: @ironX $tan(A)\:tan(B)=-1$ is definitely what's written here... 

Comment: I can't seem to get any further than: $X_x\;Y_x = -Y_y\;X_y$ using $tan$ and the `-` sign seems very odd - and incorrect. Nor does it seem to satisfy the equation :{

Comment: @ironX Not if the angles are taken to be a signed, i.e. $A-B=90$.

Comment: Note this is a proof of the well-known fact that perpendicular lines have opposite reciprocal slopes (since the tangent of these angles are the slopes of the lines).

Comment: 1. The tangent of the anticlockwise angle made by the line with the positive $x$-axis gives its gradient. 2. The product of the gradients of two perpendicular lines equals $-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition $\tan(x) \triangleq \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and trigonometric product identities ([Google them](https://www.google.com/search?q=trigonometric%20product%20identities&rlz=1C1UEAD_enUS946US946&hl=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ_c6R7vL0AhXNm-AKHekECzQQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1280&bih=601&dpr=3#imgrc=jiryXwMDHiFgVM)).

$\begin{align}
\tan(A) \tan(B) &= \frac{\sin(A)}{\cos(A)} \frac{\sin(B)}{\cos(B)}\\
&= \frac{\sin(A) \sin(B)}{\cos(A)\cos(B)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(A - B) - \cos(A + B) \right) }{\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(A + B) + \cos(A - B) \right)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(A - B) - \cos(90) \right) }{\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(90) + \cos(A - B) \right)}\\
&= \frac{\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos(A - B) - 0 \right) }{\frac{1}{2} \left(0 + \cos(A - B) \right)}\\
&= 1
\end{align}$

If the angles are taken to be signed angles, then the above proof stills works using the additional fact that $\tan(-B) = - \tan(B)$. This means that angle A is positive/anticlockwise and angle B is negative/clockwise.